# Angular+TypeScript: How to get method using HTTP Put

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, typescript1.4, typescript1.5

I am trying to fetch my all dropdown at page load using ANgularJs+TypeScript.I am done with implementing `ng-options` and `ng-init` method to load it but there might me some problem thats why i am not able to get my data from my API or to give call to my API.I have given my Code with this question.

Here is my typescript Controller:-

```
/// <reference path="../interface/interface.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />

module CustomerNew.controllers {
    export class CreateCustomerCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
        debugger;
        constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
            protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
            protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
            $scope.create = this.create;
            $scope.getFormData = this.getformData;
        }
        public getformData: (getFormData: any) => {
            $http.get();
        }
```

Giving Error AS
 It's giving error of "Property or signature expected" & Unexpected token. "A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected".
[image: Updated Error]

Comment: What are you errors ? You just give us all your code without explainations.  It's pretty easy to see that there is errors in your code. For example : `$http.get('./Deskt...` when you use `[HttpPut]`, shouldn't it be `$http.put` ? If you want a good answer explain your problem.

Comment: @Antoine Esteve i have updated my code as well and Yes It's giving error of "Property or signature expected" & Unexpected token. "A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected". 
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need **`this.`** and "=" to assign `getformData`

```
 constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
        protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
        protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
        $scope.create = this.create;
        $scope.getFormData = this.getformData;
 }
 //public getformData: (getFormData: any) => {
 public getformData = (getFormData: any) => {
    // instead of this notation
    // $http.get(...
    // we need to use this.
    this.$http.get(...
 }
```

This could be some more complex example of the above TypeScript controller defintion:

```
module CustomerNew.controllers
{
    export interface ICustomerScope extends ng.IScope
    {
        create: Function;
        getFormData: Function;
    }
    export class CreateCustomerCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];
        debugger;
        constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
            protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
            protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
            $scope.create = this.create;
            $scope.getFormData = this.getformData;
        }
        public getformData = (getFormData: any) =>
        {
            this.$http.get("url"); // ...
        }
        public create = () => { }
    }
}
```

Check it in this [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20var%20ng%3Aany%3B%0A%0Amodule%20CustomerNew.controllers%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20interface%20ICustomerScope%20extends%20ng.IScope%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20create%3A%20Function%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20getFormData%3A%20Function%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20CreateCustomerCtrl%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'%24scope'%2C%20'%24http'%2C%20'%24templateCache'%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20debugger%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20constructor(protected%20%24scope%3A%20ICustomerScope%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20protected%20%24http%3A%20ng.IHttpService%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20protected%20%24templateCache%3A%20ng.ITemplateCacheService)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24scope.create%20%3D%20this.create%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24scope.getFormData%20%3D%20this.getformData%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20getformData%20%3D%20(getFormData%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%24http.get(%22url%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20create%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) *compiler/transpiler*

Comment: Problem is not solved please see the updated error image

Comment: I added complete code snippet and a link to playground, where you can play with and check what would and what not compile/transipler...

Comment: Radim need your help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287908/angularjstypescript-how-to-get-the-selected-index-value-in-ng-select

Comment: Hi, Mico... I will check it during the day... but I cannot guarantee that I will know how to... just to be sure that you understand my limitations ... ;)

Comment: @Mico *I tried to make your scenario working, hope it helps a bit... have to get out now...*